# QRegularExpression Lineedit Validatoin

Tags: regex, qt, qregularexpression

Hello i'm trying to validate the data (consisting of names of 2 or more words) from a lineedit widget using regular expressions in qt the issue is that qt is allowing anything in the lineedit widget my code is below, thank you.

```
QRegularExpression Company_Name("/([A-Z|a-z|0-9])/g");
QRegularExpressionMatch Company_Name_Match = Company_Name.match(ui->lineEdit_Company_Name->text())
if(Company_Name_Match.hasMatch())
{
    ErrorLog = ErrorLog + "Company Name contains charagters that are not alphanumeric\n";
    ui->lineEdit_Company_Name->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red");
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i'm trying to validate the data (consisting of names of 2 or more words)

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$
```